# How to change all instances of one font to another font?

Tags: browser, fonts

I want Garamond to be used anywhere on the web where Georgia is used?

There are extensions available which change *all* fonts. I don't want that, I just want to see Georgia, instead of which, I want to see Garamond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add this to your browser: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-custom-fonts/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee)**
- and set it up like:

[image]